# Template matrix with char* consol stop responding when using operator=

Tags: c++, templates

i need some help. This is my first that hugh program in c++ (pointers are nightmare). I tried everything and i can't find what i did wrong.

```
    class aghMatrix {
private:
    T ** matrix;
    int n;
    int m;
public:
     aghMatrix() : n(0), m(0) {};
     aghMatrix(int _n, int _m);
     aghMatrix(const aghMatrix& other);
     ~aghMatrix();

     void setItem(int n, int m, T item); 
     void setItems (T * wsk);
     void setItems(int r, int c ...);
     void setAll();
     void getALL();
     bool couldbeadded(char * word, char sign);

     bool equals (T first, T second);
     T operator()(int a, int b);
     aghMatrix<T> & operator+(const aghMatrix<T> & other);
     aghMatrix<T> & operator*(const aghMatrix<T> & other);
     aghMatrix<T> & operator= ( const aghMatrix<T> & other);
     bool operator== (const aghMatrix<T> & other);
     bool operator!= (const aghMatrix<T> & other);
};
```

Test :

```
char* cpt[] = {"to", "jest", "tablica", "wyrazow", "o", "rozmiarze", "jedenascie", "ktore", "beda", "elementami", "macierzy"};
aghMatrix<char*> cpm3(3, 1);
aghMatrix<char*> cpm4;
cpm3.setItems(cpt+3);
cpm4 = cpm3; // here my consol stop responding.
```

Constructors :

```
//default
 aghMatrix() : n(0), m(0) {};
//with param
template <class T>
aghMatrix<T>::aghMatrix(int _n, int _m)
{
      n = _n;
      m = _m;
      matrix = new  T * [n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            matrix[i] = new T[m];
        }
}
```

setitems:

```
template <class T>
void aghMatrix<T>::setItems (T * wsk)
{
        int licznik = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j ++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = wsk[licznik];
                licznik ++;
            }
        }

}
```

Operator= for char*

```
template <>
aghMatrix<char*> & aghMatrix<char*>::operator= ( const aghMatrix<char*> & other)
{
            if ( & other != this) 
    {


        if ( (other.n == n) && (other.m == m) && (this->matrix != 0))
    {

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
            {
                    for (int j = 0; j < m; j ++)
                    {
                        for(int ii = 0; ii < strlen(other.matrix[i][j]); ii++)
                        {
                        matrix[i][j][ii] = other.matrix[i][j][ii];
                        }
                    }
            }


    }

    else 
    {


        if(this->matrix)
        {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j ++)
            {
                delete [] matrix[i][j];
            }

            delete [] matrix[i];
        }
        delete [] matrix;
        n = 0;
        m = 0;
        matrix = NULL;

        }

        n = other.n;
        m = other.m;
        matrix  = new char **[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            matrix[i] = new char*[m];

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j ++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = new char[strlen(other.matrix[i][j])];
                for(int ii = 0; ii < strlen(other.matrix[i][j]); ii ++)
                {
                matrix[i][j][ii] = other.matrix[i][j][ii];;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    }

    return *this;



     }
```

I tried everything and still i'm getting this problem with console (it looks like i'm using somewhere uninitialized memory or sth). I cant solve this problem alone is alone can anybody help me?

EIDT: One more thing : The error shows when the program comes to end and after i change destructor :

Now looks like this :

template

```
aghMatrix<T>::~aghMatrix()
{
    if (matrix)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        delete [] matrix[i];
    }
        delete [] matrix;
        matrix = NULL;;
        n = 0;
        m = 0;
    }


}
```

the previous version of destructor :

```
template <class T>
aghMatrix<T>::~aghMatrix()
{
    if (matrix =! 0)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        delete [] matrix[i];
    }
        delete [] matrix;
        matrix = 0;
    }


}
```

maybe here is the reason of error?

EDIT:---------------------
I found the reason of my error here it is:
when i create

```
aghMatrix<char*> cpm3(3, 1);
cpm4 = cpm3; //destructor create a problem
```

but when i do something like this:

```
aghMatrix<char*>cpm3(3,2); //or somekind of other number than '1'
cpm4 = cpm3; // everything works fine
```

any ideas?

Comment: Fyi, `strlen(other.matrix[i][j])` - it would seem to me the terminating nullchar slot was omitted from your sizing calculation (which you never set anyway). Run this under (a) a debugger and (b) Valgrind if available for your platform. And give serious consideration why `std::string` and `std::vector` aren't being used, because they should be. You also don't seem to be initializing `matrix` in your default constructor, leaving a `delete[] matrix;` invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: I fixed it
$aghMatrix() : n(0), m(0), matrix(0) {};$
and i saw something interesting :
In $operator=$  after deleting matrix the consol stop responding on this line :
 $matrix  = new char **[n];$ and which is weird because there is some of 22 test, and consols stop responding affter call return 0 but if i delete content of this operator= everything works fine. Is anybody have more idea?
PS: I can't use string and vector.

Comment: As I said, a *debugger* will reap major gains in your efforts. You gotta learn to use one sometime; may as well be now.

Comment: could you look one more time? I found error but i don't know how to solve it.